# setString error Firebase Storage: String does not match format \'base64\'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage via `putString` function on the storage reference.

I am sending data url string from my FE application to a Firebase Cloud Function and then using the `putString` function to upload it, but keeps saying:

> Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found"

I have even tried the data url from this example:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string but still the same message.

My implementation looks like:

```
const firebase_admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/storage");
const firebase_db = firebase_admin.database();
const firebase_storage = firebase.storage();

module.exports = async ({ body: { image, route } }, res) => {
  let project_id = await firebase_db.ref("/project_config/project_id").once("value")
  project_id = project_id.val()

  if (!project_id) return res.send({ message: "Project ID not found" })

  try {
    const imageType = image.split("data:")[1].split(";base64")[0]
    const storage_ref = await firebase_storage.ref().child(`${project_id}/${route}`);
    const snapshot = await storage_ref.putString(image, "data_url");
    const download_url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()

    res.send(download_url)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("----- Error during saving content data ", error)
    res.send({ message: "Error during saving your image, please re-load page and try again or contact support." })
  }
};
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'll point out that you're writing code for nodejs, but you're linking to documentation for JavaScript web clients.  Even though they are both JavaScript, the provided client libraries don't have the same APIs.  If you're on node, you need to use the node APIs.

Comment: As I found in other questions, these two imports: `const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/storage");` should enable the use of FE Firebase libraries in Node. Also since the `putString` function exists, I expect for the implementation to be correct, or am I being naive?

Comment: While you might have some success with that, I just wouldn't use those on the backend.  firebase-admin gives you access to the node API for Cloud Storage. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/